# Extracting xmin, xmax, ymin, and ymax values from circular polygons in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, coordinates, extents, arcgis-10.4

I need a way to efficiently extract the xmin, xmax, ymin, and ymax values from 66 circular plots. The plots are saved as a polygon shapefile and each plot is about 406 sq meters. I need these values to calculate `CloudMetrics` for some LiDAR data I am working with. I have access to/familiarity with R, ArcGIS 10.4.1, and ENVI 5.3. LiDAR is being analyzed in FUSION.

I've noticed that if I save each plot as an individual shapefile, ArcMap gives me the extent coordinates under the Source tab in Layer Properties. I Really don't want to do this for every plot so I am hoping there is an easier way.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the "Add Geometry Attributes" tool on your feature class, select the Extent option. This will you give you all your x min/max and y min/max values appended to the table.